# How do I Union two tables with different columns

Tags: sql

I have Two Tables Called Table_A and Table_B like bellow.

**Table_A**

```
+-------+------------+------+---------+-----+
|MonthId|DepartmentId|Salary|Deduction| Paid|
+-------+------------+------+---------+-----+
|01/2016|    DEP01   | 1000 |     100 |  900|
|01/2016|    DEP02   | 2000 |      50 | 1950|
|01/2016|    DEP03   | 1500 |       0 | 1500|
|       |            |      |         |     |
|02/2016|    DEP01   | 1000 |     100 |  900|
|02/2016|    DEP02   | 2000 |      50 | 1950|
|02/2016|    DEP03   | 1500 |       0 | 1500|
+-------------------------------------------+
```

**Table_B**

```
+-------+------------+------+---------+-----+------+------+
|MonthId|DepartmentId|Salary|Deduction| Paid|Bank_1|Bank_2|
+-------+------------+------+---------+-----+------+------+
|01/2016|    DEP01   | 1000 |     100 |  900|  400 |  500 |
|01/2016|    DEP02   | 2000 |      50 | 1950| 1400 |  550 |
|01/2016|    DEP03   | 1500 |       0 | 1500|    0 | 1500 |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

So When i try with

```
SELECT MonthId, DepartmentId, Salary, Deduction, Paid, Null AS Bank_1, Null AS Bank_2
FROM Table_A 
WHERE MonthId = '02/2016'

UNION

SELECT MonthId, DepartmentId, Salary, Deduction, Paid, Bank_1, Bank_2
FROM Table_B 
WHERE MonthId = '02/2016'
```

> WHERE MonthId = '02/2016'

im getting what i need but when if try with

> WHERE MonthId = '01/2016'

Im getting bellow Result. so please help me to solve this problem.

```
+-------+------------+------+---------+-----+------+------+
|MonthId|DepartmentId|Salary|Deduction| Paid|Bank_1|Bank_2|
+-------+------------+------+---------+-----+------+------+
|01/2016|    DEP01   | 1000 |     100 |  900| NULL | NULL |
|01/2016|    DEP01   | 1000 |     100 |  900|  400 |  500 |
|01/2016|    DEP02   | 2000 |      50 | 1950| NULL | NULL |
|01/2016|    DEP02   | 2000 |      50 | 1950| 1400 |  550 |
|01/2016|    DEP03   | 1500 |       0 | 1500| NULL | NULL |
|01/2016|    DEP03   | 1500 |       0 | 1500|    0 | 1500 |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: and what result are you expecting ?

Comment: what i'm trying is to make a crystal report via a sql view. and when i try to get data for  '01/2016' i don't wanna show null values.

Comment: so show the results you are expecting .. make it crystal clear. (I'm thinking you want to JOIN, not UNION, like Dan and Kamran below suggests), but I can't tell for sure unless you post your expected results. ;)

Comment: thank you brother, may be my question is not clear because of my bad English (Im really sorry for that). but Mr. Gordon Linoff's answer is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want aggregation:

```
SELECT MonthId, DepartmentId, Salary, Deduction, Paid, MAX(Bank_1), MAX(Bank_2)
FROM (SELECT MonthId, DepartmentId, Salary, Deduction, Paid, Null AS Bank_1, Null AS Bank_2
      FROM Table_A 
      WHERE MonthId = '02/2016'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT MonthId, DepartmentId, Salary, Deduction, Paid, Bank_1, Bank_2
      FROM Table_B 
      WHERE MonthId = '02/2016'
     ) ab
GROUP BY MonthId, DepartmentId, Salary, Deduction, Paid;
```

Comment: @Gordon can you please help here, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73006609/how-to-perform-union-of-the-tables-with-same-column-name-as-their-primary-keys-b

Answer (score 1):

I think a `LEFT JOIN` should do it:

Sample data:

```
    CREATE TABLE #Table_A (MonthId VARCHAR(10), DepartmentId varchar(10), Salary int ,Deduction int, Paid int)
INSERT INTO #Table_A
VALUES
('01/2016','DEP01','1000','100','900'),
('01/2016','DEP02','2000','50','1950'),
('01/2016','DEP03','1500','0','1500'),
('02/2016','DEP01','1000','100','900'),
('02/2016','DEP02','2000','50','1950'),
('02/2016','DEP03','1500','0','1500')

CREATE TABLE #Table_B (MonthId  VARCHAR(10), DepartmentId varchar(10), Salary int ,Deduction int, Paid int, Bank_1 int ,Bank_2 int )
INSERT INTO #Table_B
VALUES
('01/2016','DEP01','1000','100','900','400','500'),
('01/2016','DEP02','2000','50','1950','1400','550'),
('01/2016','DEP03','1500','0','1500','0','1500')
```

Query with WHERE clause:

```
SELECT  A.MonthId, 
       A.DepartmentId, 
       A.Salary, 
       A.Deduction, 
       A.Paid, 
       B.Bank_1, 
       B.Bank_2
FROM       #Table_A AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       #Table_B AS B ON A.MonthId = B.MonthId AND 
                    A.DepartmentId = B.DepartmentId AND 
                    A.Salary = B.Salary AND 
                    A.Deduction = B.Deduction AND 
                    A.Paid = B.Paid
WHERE A.MonthId = '01/2016'
```

Result:

[image]

Query without the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT  A.MonthId, 
       A.DepartmentId, 
       A.Salary, 
       A.Deduction, 
       A.Paid, 
       B.Bank_1, 
       B.Bank_2
FROM       #Table_A AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       #Table_B AS B ON A.MonthId = B.MonthId AND 
                    A.DepartmentId = B.DepartmentId AND 
                    A.Salary = B.Salary AND 
                    A.Deduction = B.Deduction AND 
                    A.Paid = B.Paid
```

Result (you will not have any values in Bank_1 ,Bank_2 for 02/2016 as there are no records for that MonthId in #Table_B ):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should be using a LEFT OUTER JOIN rather than a union, if I am correct in guessing that you want all of the values in table1, with the Bank_1 and Bank_2 values if they exist. This should work:

```
SELECT A.MonthId, A.DepartmentId, A.Salary, A.Deduction, A.Paid, B.Bank_1, B.Bank_2
FROM Table_A AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_B AS B
ON A.MonthId = B.MonthId
AND A.DepartmentId = B.DepartmentId
WHERE A.MonthId = '02/2016'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @table1 VARCHAR(255) = 'table_A' 
DECLARE @table2 VARCHAR(255) = 'table_B'

DECLARE @col1 VARCHAR(MAX) SELECT @col1 = COALESCE(@col1+',' ,'') + ISNULL(t.a, 'NULL as ' + t.b) 
FROM    
(       SELECT              
           a.COLUMN_NAME as a           
           ,b.COLUMN_NAME as b      
        FROM            
        (
                SELECT
                    COLUMN_NAME
                FROM 
                    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE 
                    TABLE_NAME = @table1            
         ) a            
         FULL JOIN
        (
                SELECT
                    COLUMN_NAME
                FROM 
                    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE 
                    TABLE_NAME = @table2            
        ) b
        ON a.COLUMN_NAME = b.COLUMN_NAME        
) t
--SELECT @cl1

DECLARE @col2 VARCHAR(MAX) SELECT @col2 = COALESCE(@col2+',' ,'') + ISNULL(t.b, 'NULL as ' + t.a) 
FROM    
(       SELECT              
           a.COLUMN_NAME as a           
           ,b.COLUMN_NAME as b      
        FROM            
        (
                SELECT
                    COLUMN_NAME
                FROM 
                    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE 
                    TABLE_NAME = @table1            
         ) a            
         FULL JOIN              
         (
                SELECT
                    COLUMN_NAME
                FROM 
                    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE 
                    TABLE_NAME = @table2            
         ) b            
         ON a.COLUMN_NAME = b.COLUMN_NAME       
) t
--SELECT @table2


DECLARE @DynSQL nvarchar(MAX) Set @DynSQL = 'SELECT ' + @col1 + ' FROM ' + @table1 + ' UNION ALL SELECT ' + @col2 + ' FROM ' + @table2


exec sp_executesql @DynSQL
```