# How to perform UNION of the tables with same column name as their primary keys but different values

Tags: sql, select, where-clause, union

These are the two tables:
Input:

```
Employees table:
+-------------+----------+
| employee_id | name     |
+-------------+----------+
| 2           | Crew     |
| 4           | Haven    |
| 5           | Kristian |
+-------------+----------+
Salaries table:
+-------------+--------+
| employee_id | salary |
+-------------+--------+
| 5           | 76071  |
| 1           | 22517  |
| 4           | 63539  |
+-------------+--------+
```

I want an output like how you perform join but using the union.

The output of the union should look like this:

```
employee_id   | name       | salary 
2              crew.        null 
4.             haven.       63539 
5.             Kristian     76071
1.             null.        22517
```

and post doing the union I want to perform select, by selecting the employee_id on employees with either no name or no salary

Query currently I am working on :

```
select * from 
(select employee_id, name, null as salary from employees 
union all 
select employee_id, null as name, salary from salaries) 
as emp 
where name is null or salary is null
```

The result looks like this:

```
{"headers": ["employee_id", "name", "salary"], "values": [[2, "Crew", null], [4, "Haven", null], [5, "Kristian", null], [5, null, 76071], [1, null, 22517], [4, null, 63539]]}
```

if use this query:

```
select * from (select employee_id, name from employees union all select employee_id, salary from salaries) as emp
```

the result looks like this:

```
{"headers": ["employee_id", "name"], "values": [[2, "Crew"], [4, "Haven"], [5, "Kristian"], [5, "76071"], [1, "22517"], [4, "63539"]]}
```

Comment: Also, this question is from leet code; I could look up the solution directly, but please don’t provide any immediate solutions; I would appreciate your hints on solving this. As I have been trying this one for a long time. So finally reaching out for the help of you guys

Comment: Are you sure that you are using MySql? You accepted an answer that uses FULL join but MySql does not support it.

Comment: Plan A:  `UNION ALL` plus `GROUP BY`.  Plan B:  `LEFT JOIN .. UNION ALL .. RIGHT + IS NULL`  If you are still interested, I will spell them out further.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a full join:

```
Select coalesce(e.employeeid, s.employeeid) employed
       e.name, e.salary
From employees e full join
     Salaries s
     On e.employeeid = s.employeeid
```